# How to re-disable (disable) the text box on clicking a button or a link?

Tags: javascript

I have a script that enables the disabled text box when clicking on a button. But, I just don't know how to re-disable the text box again.

The coding is below.

HTML:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <label for="some-tbox" class="input-group-addon">Label:</label>
  <input id="some-tbox" type="text" class="input-box" value="some value" disabled>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="enable" type="button">button</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    $(".enable").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().children(".input-box").removeAttr("disabled");
        $(this).toggleClass("disable");
        $(this).toggleClass("enable");
    });

    $(".disable").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("enable");
        $(this).toggleClass("disable");
        $(this).parent().parent().children(".input-box").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
```

And I have made a fiddle out of it. But, It's not working. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/5gpj21fa/2/) is the link.

Comment: is your javascript is in separate file or same file? if it is in separate file you must include it using script tag right??

Comment: in your fiddle also, it's showing your jquery file is not found...

Comment: The javascript is in the same file. Its working when I click on the button. But, couldn't re-disable it.

Comment: @Abbas,  I don't know how to add the external link to fiddle. I'm new. Could you please edit the fiddle for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of messing with adding and removing classes, just toggle the disabled property with:

```
$(".enable").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.input-group').find('input').prop('disabled', !$(this).closest('.input-group').find('input').prop('disabled'))
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/k8vdohw6/)**

Comment: Thank you. This was the exact answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line `$(".disable").click(function(){ ...})`

You are binding a click event handler to a class named `disabled` which was not available initially during page load, it appears dynamically later.

You need to delegate the event handler to some parent which always exist and then handle the event there, in this case you can do this:

```
    $(".input-group").on('click', '.disable', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("enable");
        $(this).toggleClass("disable");
        $(this).parent().parent().children(".input-box").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
```

[jQuery's on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function

Answer (score 0):

You cann't bind an element ".disable" that don't exist , In that case you can rebind it when you changed it's class. Code behind may help you:

```js
      $(".enable").on("click",enabledClick)
    function enabledClick (argument) {
        $(".enable").parent().parent().children(".input-box").removeAttr("disabled");
        $(".enable").toggleClass("disable");
        $(".enable").toggleClass("enable");
        $(".disable").on("click",disabledClick)
   
    }


    function disabledClick (argument) {
   $(".disable").parent().parent().children(".input-box").attr("disabled", "");
     $(".disable").toggleClass("enable");
        $(".disable").toggleClass("disable");
        $(".enable").on("click",enabledClick)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Jack.